# how to export client from index.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, client

I'm making a "utils.js" file, which serves to have some interesting functions and I would like to know if there is a way for me to pull the client from my index.js to this file and how to do this. I wanted to do this so that when using the "embed" function I wouldn't need to pass the client as a parameter and I would always have to inform the client.

[image: code]

Comment: Read about [Javascript modules](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-modules-explained-with-examples/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but I guess you could export the client from your index.js file, and then define it in your utils.js.

**index.js**

```js
import { Client } from "discord.js";

const client = new Client({ intents: }) // Add your intents here

export default client;
```

**utils.js**

```js
import client from "./index.js";

function embed(text) {
    // Add your logic here
}
```

Now I don't know how useful the code above will be, since for your embed function to do anything you'd have to call it to your main file which is your index.js file, since that is where you authenticate the bot.

Now the best approach for working with multiple files, in my opinion, is to have your main file (index.js) define the client, do the basic necessary stuff like authenticating the bot, define event handlers, export your functions/logic from your other files, and then call it in your index.js file like this:

**utils.js**

```
export function embed(client, test) {
    // Add your logic here
}
```

**index.js**

```
import { Client } from "discord.js";
import { embed } from "./utils.js"; // Import your embed function

const client = new Client({ intents:  }) // Add your intents here

embed(client);
```